# Win 2008R2 - Increase available memory without reboot

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2

On my Windows 2008 R2 box, I have setup "Max Available Memory" in the advanced options of `msconfig > boot` to 4GB. I have 8GB of memory physically installed in the server.

Can I increase the "Max Available Memory" to make use of all available memory without rebooting the server?

Comment: Where exactly did you set this limit? 
Do you mean Virtual memory maximum size in Advanced Options?

Comment: In the MSCONFIG utility under the BOOT tab, you can open up a window to configure advanced boot options. This basically sets kernel parameters in the boot.ini file.

Comment: I assume this can't be done without system restart, since OS needs to re-initialize extra RAM/CPU.

Answer (score 2):

After changing this configuration, you must reboot the server for Windows to begin using the increased amount of memory.